# Как отменить overflow:hidden, для дочернего элемента

Tags: css, css3, html5

Есть вот такая вёрстка которую нельзя ломать.

```css
.form-line__box {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  padding: 3em 3em;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background: #293744;
  background-position-x: 0%;
  background-position-y: 0%;
  background-image: none;
  background-size: auto;
  color: #fff;
}

.select__list {
  background: transparent;
  border: 1px solid #467797;
  margin: 0px 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-line__box">
  <div class="g-row g-row_flex g-ai_c_md">
    <div class="g-col g-col_md_6">


      <div class="g-mb_2_xs g-mb_0_md">
        <p class="h2 h2_no_line g-clr_inh">Получите единый инструмент<br> управления вашим бизнесом</p>
        <p>Оставьте заявку и получите подробную <br> консультацию наших специалистов.</p>
      </div>

    </div>
    <form class="g-col form-dark g-col_md_6 js-validated" action="?" novalidate="novalidate">
      <fieldset class="">
        <ul class="form-line__list g-row">
          <li class="form-line__item g-col g-col_md_6">
            <label>
                                            <span class="form-dark__label">Имя*</span>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-dark__field" name="name">
                                        </label>
          </li>
          <li class="form-line__item g-col g-col_md_6">
            <label>
                                            <span class="form-dark__label">Телефон*</span>
                                            <input type="tel" name="phone" class="form-dark__field js-mask">
                                        </label>
          </li>
          <li class="form-line__item g-col g-col_md_6">
            <label>
                                            <span class="form-dark__label">E-mail*</span>
                                            <input type="email" name="email" class="form-dark__field js-mask">
                                        </label>
          </li>
          <li class="form-line__item g-col g-col_md_6" style="z-index: 100;">
            <label>
                                                <span class="form-dark__label">Тип компании</span>
                                                
                                                    <div class="select"><div class="select__gap form-dark__field on active"><ul class="select__list" style="">
        <li class="select__item" data-value="Фитнес-клуб"><span>Фитнес-клуб</span></li>
        <li class="select__item" data-value="Танцевальная школа"><span>Танцевальная школа</span></li>
        <li class="select__item" data-value="Йога-центр"><span>Йога-центр</span></li>
        <li class="select__item" data-value="Кросфит"><span>Кросфит</span></li>
        <li class="select__item" data-value="Велнес-центр"><span>Велнес-центр</span></li>
        <li class="select__item" data-value="Школа единоборств"><span>Школа единоборств</span></li>
        <li class="select__item" data-value="Теннисный клуб"><span>Теннисный клуб</span></li>
        <li class="select__item" data-value="Бассейн"><span>Бассейн</span></li><li class="select__item" data-value="Детский развивающий центр"><span>Детский развивающий центр</span></li>
        <li class="select__item" data-value="Стретчинг"><span>Стретчинг</span></li>
        <li class="select__item" data-value="Салон красоты"><span>Салон красоты</span></li>
    
    </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
        
                                            </label>
          </li>
          <li class="form-line__item g-col g-col_md_6">
            <span class="form-dark__label g-hide_xs g-show_md">&nbsp;</span>

            <input type="submit" class="btn btn_sz" value="Оставить заявку" style="width: 100%; font-size: 14px;">

          </li>
        </ul>
        <input type="hidden" name="group" value="free-schedule">
      </fieldset>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

`.select__list` - это выподающий список. Проблема в том что из-за overflow:hidden у `.form-line__box` он обрезается по границам родителя.
Как конкретно для `.select__list` отменить `overflow:hidden;`?

Comment: Никак. Это свойство не наследуется.

Comment: position: absolute; уберите

Answer (score -1):

```
.form-line__box {overflow:visible;}
```